# Set JFrame and Componets according to screen resolution?

Tags: java, swing

In Swing Application, JFrame is not changing its size behaviour according to screen resolution.

I tried

```
pack();
```

and

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension d = toolkit.getScreenSize();
height = d.height;
width = d.width;
this.setSize(width, height);
```

and

```
GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
    width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
    height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
```

Using GraphicsDevice there is no change.

When I change resolution JFrame and components goes behind the taskbar and complete frame will not display.

I want JFrame and all components to resize according to various screen resolutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777135/java-jframe-size-according-to-screen-resolution?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java JFrame Size according to screen resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777135/java-jframe-size-according-to-screen-resolution)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```